How do I rewrite the document root in a Laravel 9.x application?
I recently deployed a Laravel 9.x application into a sub-directory on a shared hosting environment like so subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory. I know it's not recommended but I now, want to rewrite the document root from /, to /subdirectory. Is it possible, and if yes, how do I go about.
I've tried rewriting the app url in the .env, and config.php, but nothing changes. When I specify the subdirectory in the routes, the app defaults to a Not Found page
I've also tried specifying the re-routing in a .htaccess likeso:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

but nothing changes. The app is hosted on cPanel
